# Simulate history.back() in enzyme

Tags: javascript, jestjs, enzyme

For a react component test i need to simulate a browser back. Is this possible with a mounted component?

What i've tried:

```js
it('triggers onpopstate events', () => {
   requiredProps.filterBlocks = mockData.filterBlocks;

   const wrapper = mount(<FilterBlocks {...requiredProps} />);

   global.window.history.pushState({ mock: 'MOCK'}, "mock", "mock.html");
   global.window.history.pushState({ mock: 'MOCK2'}, "mock", "mock2.html");

   global.window.history.back();


   expect(mockedFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

Inside the component (componentDidMount) i have a window.onpopstate listener:

```js
window.onpopstate = event => {
    console.log('event', event);
};
```

But nothing will be logged to console.

Answer (score 2):

For my test i triggered onpopstate manuelly with:

```
const testEvent = { target: "mock" };

global.window.onpopstate(testEvent);
```